# EPPlus set default worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I am using EPPlus v4.1 to generate an excel file in C#.

Is there a way to set a specific worksheet as the default worksheet?  (when the user is opening the exported file, that sheet should be shown)

I could not find a method or property on `ExcelWorkbook` or `ExcelWorksheets` classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer meanwhile. I don't want to delete the question because it might be useful to someone else.

```
//this line sets the first tab in the excel file as default/active
    Workbook.Worksheets.First().Select();
```

Answer (score 1):

For EPPlus 5 the answer is:

```
sheet.View.SetTabSelected();
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked in my case (not sure what was specific about my particular case), but I was able to set the active worksheet using the below (using EPPlus v4.5.3.3):

```
excelPackage.Workbook.View.ActiveTab = worksheet.Index;
```